# Display only last part of string

Tags: css

How to display only last part of string, if it more than my `div` width without line breaks?
E.g. "`...string`" instead of

```
This is my
very large string
```

UPD: 
[This](http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/12/16/css-riddle-reverse-ellipsis/) solution works, but when i have a large word, e.g. url `http://myhost/path/foo/bar?and=some&params=there` displays only part of symbol, it is not good. Any ideas?

Comment: http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/12/16/css-riddle-reverse-ellipsis/

Comment: thanks, it is works, but not in all cases. Please, see updated question fore more information.

Comment: No, it's doubtful if it would work in **all** cases. It's not a standard request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `direction: rtl;` but its not going to work in Chrome

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div>This is my
very large string</div>
```

Or you can use **JQuery** and take last word from text, also the width of `p` will be dynamic and adjust to width of last word.

```js
var part = $('p').text().split(' ');
$('p').text('... '+part[part.length-1]);
```

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is my
very large string</p>
```

Comment: unfortunately, my users use Chrome mostly(

Comment: hmm seems to work in Chrome on 24 november 2017... does this mean that the top version is the recommended way? I like CSS solution above JQuery